# Cut and store a string untill a word is found in bash

Tags: bash, sed, cut-command

I have this string

```
/path/to/www/continued/xyz
```

I want to cut the string till www means I want the string

```
/path/to/www
```

How can I do this in bash

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/495930/how-can-we-remove-text-from-start-to-some-particular-selected-word-using-sed-com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed  's/www.*$/www/' file
```

where file is the file containing this type of strings.

```
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ sed  's/www.*$/www/' <<< "/path/to/www/continued/xyz"
/path/to/www
```

If you have the string in a variable `var` then run

```
echo $var | sed  's/www.*$/www/'
```

Comment: I just have a string not a file

Comment: Where do you have the string?

Comment: @Pilot6.Actually he has given the String and he wants to cut out a particular section from it.

Comment: The question was where was that string to cut from. In a file, a variable, or where?

Answer (score -3):

Just write the following command in bash.It will do the work.

> cut -c1-12

And for more information check out this link.You will be clear after that.

> http://www.folkstalk.com/2012/02/cut-command-in-unix-linux-examples.html

Comment: It will work only for this specific string. If you have only one string, you do not need to automate it. You can just do it manually.

Comment: This is non- sense. The string before `www` can have different lengths.

Comment: But the OP asked for the particular question's solution.Why have I been downvoted? My solution is right and i am sure of it.

Comment: You have to understand that `/path/to` is not an existing path. It could be anything, with any length. Can be on a server, can be on a backup location...  A solution needs to be smart and take `www` as an identifying string.

Comment: I know that and I don't think we are talking about fields and delimiters here.But either it's not a properly formatted question or if the question is right then from my thinking the OP asked if given a string /path/to/www/continued/xyz how will he get the string  /path/to/www

Comment: Well, it seems kind of obvious that OP does not *literally* mean `/path/to`, and asks for a "smart" solution to get the path until, and including, `www`. Be sure it is nothing personal by the way, this is how it works :)